# LINQ creating anonymous type array error

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, anonymous-types

I am trying to create a array of anonymous type from the result set using LINQ.

my code is

```
var data = (from s in sortedStudents
            select new
            {
                //id = s.CurrencyId,
                cell = new object[] { s.PropertyNumber.ToString(), s.Name,
                s.Status.ToString(), "Hello" }
            }).ToArray();
```

But I am getting an error as below, but I have not used any System.Int64 variable.

> Unable to cast the type 'System.Int64' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ
>   to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.

Any ideas what is wrong here.

After spending sometime I suspect that my logic for sorting the data is creating the problem, my code for sorting the date is

```
// Utility method to sort IQueryable given a field name as "string"
    // May consider to put in a cental place to be shared
    public IQueryable<T> SortIQueryable<T>(IQueryable<T> data, string fieldName, string sortOrder)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fieldName)) return data;
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sortOrder)) return data;

        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "i");
        Expression conversion = Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(param, fieldName), typeof(object));
        var mySortExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(conversion, param);

        return (sortOrder == "desc") ? data.OrderByDescending(mySortExpression)
            : data.OrderBy(mySortExpression);
    }
```

Now when I my the column name whose type is system.int64, then its creating problem, as execution of query takes place actually when i do .ToArray to the results.

Comment: Why isn't `cell` a `string[]`? All entries seem to be strings.

Comment: cell is object[] as it will contain Id also, right now all values string because i was trying to find which column was creating problems.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely in your sorting logic, namely this line:

```
Expression conversion = Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(param, fieldName), typeof(object));
```

As the error message states, LINQ to Entities does not support this type of conversion. You will either need to execute the query beforehand with a `.ToList()` or reformulate your sorting logic.

Comment: I agree the problem is in this statement, but what could be solutions ?

Comment: Before you call your `SortIQueryable` method, try evaluating the existing expression with a `.ToList()` or `.AsEnumerable()`. This will use LINQ to Objects for all further expressions.